# the CSS and all the HTML tags are correct yet my ivu date picker icon is mis aligned. is there a problem with the verson of my VUE js?

Tags: vuejs2

I am new to vue js and I am facing an issue with the datepicker icon misaligned. It is going above the input tag.

I am using vue@2.6.8

datepicker icon shout be aligned

[image: misaligned icon tag]

Comment: can you please show the code?

Comment: You should use any style-sheet framework like Bootstrap, bulma or vuetify. They have nice components for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below `css` to fix that alignment issue.

```
.ivu-date-picker-editor .ivu-input-suffix {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 11;
   right: 8px;
   margin-top: 7px;
}
```